# How to check first element of an array 1 with all elements in array 2, then second element in array 2, repeat, using JS for loop? or a JS method?

Tags: javascript

How to check first element of an array 1 with all elements in array 2, then second element in array 2, repeat, using JS for loop? or a JS method?

```
var array1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']

var array2 = ['43','24','35','42','55','63','1']
```

So, in the above code, we would check all elements in array1 against 43, then all elements in array 1 against 24 etc.

The output would remove any instances from array1 that match any instances in array 2 and add it to the end. So the output would be

```
array1 = ['2','3','4','5','6','7', '1']
```

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: The output would remove any instances from array1 that match any instances in array 2 and add it to the end. So the output would be var array1 = ['2','3','4','5','6','7', '1']

Comment: @MagicJS, so you want the element that is on array2 to be added to the last?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/5743676

Comment: @Sunil Lama https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/pig-latin, I'm trying to remove the first cluster of consonants (if they are consonants, not vowels) and add them to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

u can do that with simple loop or u can use lodash library:)

```
_.difference([2, 1], [2, 3]);

// => [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `forEach` on first array.

For example:

```
array1.forEach(elem1 => {
  var index = array2.indexOf(elem1);
  if (index != -1) {
    array2.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    array2.push(elem1);
  }
});
```

In this example you iterate through `array1` and search for position of each array1 element. If you find one, then it will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to segregate values of `array1` into unique array and repeating array and then `array#concat` both of them.

```js
var array1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'],
    array2 = ['43','24','35','42','55','63','1'],
    set = new Set(array2);
    
var result = array1.reduce((r,v) => (set.has(v) ? r.repeating.push(v) : r.unique.push(v), r), {unique:[], repeating:[]});

var output = result.unique.concat(result.repeating);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can also use `array#includes` to check for value in the other array.

```js
var array1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'],
    array2 = ['43','24','35','42','55','63','1'];
    
var result = array1.reduce((r,v) => (array2.includes(v) ? r.repeating.push(v) : r.unique.push(v), r), {unique:[], repeating:[]});

var output = result.unique.concat(result.repeating);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```